# RandomAccessFile over HTTP

Tags: java, http

It's easy to open a connection to a remote asset using URL.openStream() which returns an InputStream. What about random access?

Answer (score 4):

HTTP 1.1 allows retrieval of parts of a resource through use of [Byte Ranges](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35), but...

- servers are [not required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35.2) to support it
- you will incur extra overhead due extra request/response headers, (possibly) establishing extra network connections, etc.

Answer (score 2):

True random access is not possible via http. You can simulate it though by passing a starting point as a paramater and return a stream that represents data from that position onwards.

For example this is how progressive HTTP download works (e.g. YouTube video seek).