# how to tell the http server stop sending redundant bytes that i previously requested through "get"?

Tags: java, http, clojure

Say I want to download a file on a http server which supports segmenting downloading, making use of range header. For example:

- url to the file: www.music.com/rock.mp3
- length of file: 4000 bytes

Say I launched two threads and each is downloading half of bytes of file.

- thread t1 downloads bytes from 0 to 1999
- thread t2 downloads bytes from 2000 to 3999

Say that t2 finished downloading the later half, and t1 only downloaded up to bytes 1199 yet, so t1 still has bytes 1200 to 1999 to go, which is 800 bytes in total.

Now I let t2 start downloading from byte 1600 to byte 1999, and I want t1 keep downloading up to bytes 1599. I see no problem of doing this with t2, I just need to send another get message with range from 1600 to 1999. But t1 originally sent get message from range 0 to 1999, not from 0 to 1599, so the server will keep sending bytes to t1 until the byte 1999 is delivered anyway, which in t1's perspective include redundant bytes from 1600 to 1999..

1. So for t1, is there any way to tell the server that, "ok plan changed, I only need up to 1599, so stop at the point when you sent 1599, don't send bytes from 1600"? One "workaround" that I can come up with is just letting t1 discard any bytes from byte 1600 to 1999, but these bytes are still being delivered over the wire, so they still consume the bandwidth and affect the network throughput, and it's not what I want... I am trying to design a dynamic segmenting scheme to boost up the downloading speed, so that's why I am concerned with speed and throughput here. I imagine if it's a large file, say maybe 1gigabytes, and using two threads, then in a worst case, the redundant bytes I have to discard would be around half of a gigabyte and that's a lot... One person mentioned simply terminating the connection. I wonder, when the server heard the connection closing request from me, will the server instantly stop sending any more unsent bytes in the requested range, like bytes 1678, 1830 etc. --- I know that before server actually hears the connection closing request, it might still send couple redundant bytes; well discarding that much byte is not a big issue though.
2. Is there any other ways to make dynamic segmentation work, other than what I have so far?
3. In above scenario, when t2 finished its job from 2000 to 3999 and about to grab bytes from 1600 to 1999, will t2 use the same http connection to grab new range of bytes by default or I should do something beforehand(for example, sending extra argument to GET message etc.) to make it happen? And am I right that in such case, using same connection is better than closing and opening another connection?

I am writing this in clojure, so if you have any code example in java or clojure, that would be really helpful. :-)

Comment: Some HTTP servers supports `Range` header.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212108/randomaccessfile-over-http).

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I know that to download in segments, the server must support range header in first hand.. but I am not sure once my thread t1 requested range 0 to 1999, than later I don't want the portion 1600 to 1999, than how should I let the server stop sending me the redundant portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So imagine you want to download a 4M file and want two threads to do it. Wouldn't it be nice to have the first thread getting from 0 towards the middle, and the second thread bytes from the end towards the middle? Thats the first thing that came to mind when looking at this problem.

Since you can request ranges you can either terminate the connection when you got enough or you can work in blocks. A 4MB file would by 1024 blocks of 4k. The two threads gets blocks from either side and you stop when you got those 1024 blocks without caring which thread got more.

But this is actually only visually pleasing. If you have a counter c of n blocks you can use it to have a number of threads, based on the size of the download and a maximum limit of threads. All can claim the first free block by incrementing the counter and storing that as it's job. If something happens you need to make sure the threads job gets done. Other than that you'll be done when the counter reaches n and all threads are done.

I was thinking bitset, but I think you have enough control by knowing current job for each thread and that counter. Make sure the method incrementing it is synchronized though.

Comment: How should I download bytes from the end towards middle? I mean is it possible for a http server to send bytes to the client, from higher bytes index to lower bytes index? I thought a client can only get bytes from lower index to higher index.

Comment: You mentioned terminating the connection when I get enough data --- so if thread t1 originally requested 0 to 1999 and now t1 only needs 0 to 1599 and say t1 just got the 1599th byte, then if I terminate the connection of t1 with server at this point, and once the server heard that back from me, will server instantly stop sending bytes in the previously requested range but not sent yet? I am a noob in networking so there are many things that I am unclear about. :-)

Comment: @SevenHong From end towards the middle was an ideal view. If you divide in blocks you can ask for the last and first block it's very close. Sending will stop when connection closes. If you download an ISO and regret it you have a cancel button in your browser. The browser simply closes the connection.

Comment: Gee! Thanks! I think you cleared the most confusing part of my questions!